# Determining Bounds of Theta for Double Integration of a Polar Region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, upper-lower-bounds, bounds-of-integration

Given the region $$ R:(x, y | x^2 + y^2 \le 4x) $$ And given the function $f(x, y) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, find the double integral of the polar region.

So upon sketching the graph we get a circle with a radius of $2$ centered at $(2,0)$. Converting the given eqn. of $f(x, y)$ into polar coordinates we get that $r^2 \le 4x$, which can be converted to $r^2 \le 4rcos\theta$, and then simplified to $r = 4cos\theta$.

Okay sounds good right? I currently have my region set up in the following manner,

$$D:{(r,\theta)|0\le r\le 4cos\theta, 0 \le \theta \le }$$

however, I'm confused on how to find the upper bound for theta. Without this I can't properly evaluate the double integral, can anyone help me in figuring out how to find this upper bound for theta and why it is so? It cannot be $\frac{\pi}{2}$ because that only encompasses the top half of the circle, the region consists of the entire circle, whose the other half lies in the 4th quadrant.

I will provide a picture of my current work below.

Thank you!

[Current Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j5Va.png)

Comment: 'The region consists of the **entire** circle...'

Comment: Wow, what a brain fart! Thank you!

Comment: Your working is correct. Please use $-\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the polar coordinates
$$x=r\cos(\theta)\;\;,\;\; y=\sin(\theta)$$
then, because the circle with $ (2,0) $
as center and $ R=2$ as radius, is tangent to the $y-$ axis, at the origine,
the angle $ \theta $ will variate between $ -\frac \pi2 $ and $ +\frac \pi2 $.

for each $ \theta $, we have
$$0\le r \le R_{max} $$
with
$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{2+2\cos(2\theta)}{R_{max}}$$
thus

$$R_{max}=4\cos(\theta)$$
So,
$$D=\{(r,\theta)| -\frac \pi2\le \theta\le \frac \pi2 \text{ and } 0\le r\le 4\cos(\theta)\}$$

Comment: There is nothing wrong with OP's choice of parameterization.

Comment: @MathLover $x=r\cos(t), y=r\sin(t)$ is correct when the center is $(0,0)$

Comment: that's not true. $0 \leq r \leq 4 \cos\theta, - \pi/2 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$ is a parametrization that will work for the given circle with center at $(2,0)$ and with radius $2$. It works for circles with center on x-axis and y-axis being a tangent of the circle.

Comment: The angle and radial distance is being measured from the origin whereas in your parametrization, the angle is being measured from the center of the circle.

Comment: Now, i think the answer is correct.